# How can I clear all cookies while executing retrofit API call?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2

I want to clear all cookies while executing specific API call in Android and I have tried by using CookieManager class but unable to remove all cookies which are passing through API call is there any way available to do so or is it possible to clear cookies in retrofit

Here is my code which I am using to remove cookies

```
cookieManager.cookieStore.removeAll()
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the code below, it works perfectly.

```
CookieHandler cookieHandler = new CookieManager(
            new PersistentCookieStore(context), CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL);
    // initialising okhttp 3 logger bwlow
    HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
    // initialising OkHttpClient below
    OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .cookieJar(new JavaNetCookieJar(cookieHandler))
            .addInterceptor(logging)
            .build();
```

Comment: I want to remove cookies for specific API call (Ex. API A should be called by removing cookies and API B should be called by not removing)

is this work like that?